# I need to display a Cesiumjs HTML file in AR

Tags: gis, cesiumjs, wms, ar.js

I currently have an HTML file, I used cesiumjs. I need to display this in AR and built it as a mobile app. For building a mobile app I am using Cordova. I almost searched every forum and it's not possible because of AR only supports 3D formats like gltf,fbx e.t.c. Can anyone help me with the AR part ? [I need to get the output something similar like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Llb.jpg). I need to get the WMS source from the user in realtime.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <script src="https://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.44/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
    <style>
      @import url(https://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.44/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css);
      #cesiumContainer {position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;}
        
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
    <script>
var widget = new Cesium.CesiumWidget('cesiumContainer');
 contextOptions : {
            alpha : true
        }
    

    widget.scene.skyBox.destroy();
    widget.scene.skyBox = undefined;
    widget.scene.sun.destroy();
    widget.scene.sun = undefined;
    widget.scene.skyAtmosphere.destroy();
    widget.scene.skyAtmosphere = undefined;
    widget.scene.backgroundColor = new Cesium.Color(0, 0, 0, 0);

var url='https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gebco_web_services/2019/mapserv'; //Geoserver URL
var layers = widget.scene.globe.imageryLayers;
    layers.removeAll();
    layers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
        url : url,        
        layers: 'GEBCO_2019_Grid_2'// layer name
        
                

    }));

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Mr.Krabs I can not see your Ar.js code, also i have very little experience with Cesium, Does Cesium has Three.js in the core? if yes i think that is possible.

Comment: Maybe this article may help you: https://cesium.com/blog/2017/10/23/integrating-cesium-with-threejs/

Comment: Hey, the output of the above is what I want to display in AR. I checked that article before but it's only for importing 3D objects from Three.js right?